# Problemas em fazer o POST no Django

Tags: python, django, back-end, python-requests, anaconda

Estou em uma parte do projeto, que é a pagina de registros

[image: Imagem do Forms]

Fiz a criação do metodo da View mas ainda não está rolando

[image: Imagem do metodo na view]

Pelo que olhei o botão está ok.

[image: Img Admin]

A ultima imagem é do meu admin, onde não esta aparecendo os novos usuarios

Answer (score 2):

Faltou salvar no banco de dados. segue um exemplo:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        nome = request.POST['nome']
        email = request.POST['email']
        senha = request.POST['password']
        senha2 = request.POST['password2']
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=nome, email=email, password=senha,)
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'usuarios/cadastro.html')
```

Comment: Continua não salvando...

Answer (score 0):

Tente com a Class based views:

formulario:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class CadastroForm(UserCreationForm):
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Na lista fields, são o nomes padrão do user do django, esta reaproveitando as.
No teu caso seria apenas email e senha mas fica aqui a referencia.

View:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import CadastroForm

    class Usuario(CreateView):
        form_class = CadastroForm
        template_name = 'cadastro.html'
      #  success_url = reverse_lazy('sucesso') #redireciona para algum lugar
      # ou as mensagens personalidadas do cbv
      # Pode dar erro indicando falta de redirecionamento se não tratar.
```

urls:

```
from .views import  Usuario
urlpatterns = [

      path('cadastrar/', Usuario.as_view())
```

html:

```
<form method="post">

    {%csrf_token%}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">salvar</button>
</form>
```

Confirme olhando no banco de Dados se o dados foram salvos.